# How to lock the first suggestion on the address bar

Tags: firefox

I recently had to do a clean reinstall of Firefox so I lost my history. I was accustomed to just typing "f" and getting Facebook as my first suggest site. Now it's the second choice, and I don't know how to move it back up to the first. Is there any way to manually adjust the "suggested site" feature of Firefox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, I think a better solution would be use a bookmark **keyword**.

---

### Setup:

1. **Bookmark** a location.

   [image: bookmark]
2. Open the **Library** (`Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks`)

   [image: show all bookmarks]
3. **Find** the bookmark.

   > **Note**: If you did not pick a folder for the bookmark, the default folder is `Unsorted Bookmarks`.

   [image: unsorted bookmarks]
4. **Select** the bookmark and **click** `More` to show the `Keyword` field. Now, enter a keyword of one or more characters.

   [image: keyword]
5. Close the Library

---

### Example:

Now you can quickly load a location (**regardless of history**) by just typing a keyword!

[image: example]

> **Tip 1**: You can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> immediately after typing a keyword to launch it's location. Normally, you would have to press <kbd>Down</kbd> first to select a location.
>
> **Tip 2:** Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will avoid the `Switch to tab` behavior, if the location is already open in a different tab. *This applies to the address bar in general*.

---

### Video Demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKW9Vy-vHQ8

Comment: Awesome, this works pretty well. Only downside is if I already have a tab open with that page, then the first option is "Switch to Tab" instead of making a new window, but hey, beggars can't be choosers. Thanks for the great formatting and effort.

Comment: Today, you get to beg and choose! Press `[Alt]`+`[Enter]` to avoid the `Switch to tab` behavior, if the location is already open in a different tab. :)

Comment: Although, if you are using a keyword, you do not need to press `[Down]` to launch its location.

Answer (score 1):

With the cursor hovering over the site in the drop down list, simply press the delete key to remove the suggested site

Comment: It only removes it for that one instance. If I try again, it shows up how it did before.